# Counting Numbers Like meter counting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have got this lovely task,which i know improve my knowledge, but one logic let share with you,
suppose i have set cols 4
and range will 1-9
i want this output

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
1,2,3,7
1,2,3,8
1,2,3,9
1,2,4,5
1,2,4,6
1,2,4,7
1,2,4,8
1,2,4,9
1,2,5,6
1,2,5,7
1,2,5,8
1,2,5,9
1,2,6,7
1,2,6,8
1,2,6,9
1,2,7,8
1,2,7,9
1,2,8,9
so on
```

when range satisfy, the prev col nubmer will increase and when that col range satisfy then the another prev col incrase and so on,

```js
for(i = 1 i<=9 i++)
  {
  what next plz describe  
  }
```

or give any relevant example,
Thanks
Warm Regards,
Tahir

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
for (i=1; i<=9; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; j<=9; j++)
    {
        for (k=j+1; k<=9; k++)
        {
            for (l=k+1; l<=9; l++)
            {
                printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, l);
            }
        }
    }
}
```